# I am facing an issue while achieving collision behavior in android it was working few days ago

Tags: java, android, maps, google-maps-markers

I am using 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'

and using advance marker for achieving collision behavior

this is my code block

```
int collisionBehavior = AdvancedMarkerOptions.CollisionBehavior.OPTIONAL_AND_HIDES_LOWER_PRIORITY;
            AdvancedMarkerOptions options = new AdvancedMarkerOptions()
                    .zIndex(0)
                    .position(hotelLocation)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(this, customMarkerView,false)))
                    .collisionBehavior(collisionBehavior);

            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(options);
```

All I can find is this exception:

```
GoogleApiManager: Failed to get service from broker. 
    java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2376)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2360)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2343)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2285)
        at m.cqy.q(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:180)
        at m.cpk.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234210309@234210304065.587101654.587101654:54)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle files?